ASP.NET in VB, troubles with getting values from Form
I'm new with ASP.NET and I'm studying on the Dan Mabbutt, Adam Freeman and Matthew MacDonald book "Pro ASP.NET 4.5 in VB" (ISBN 978-1-4302-4353-3).
I coded the first example on chapter 1, a simple web form with some data to be read by VB application on the server. Here is the code:
Public Class GuestResponse
Public Property Name() As String
Public Property Email() As String
Public Property Phone() As String
Public Property WillAttend() As Nullable(Of Boolean)
End Class

Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class ResponseRepository

   Private Shared repository As New ResponseRepository()
   Private responses As New List(Of GuestResponse)()

   Public Shared Function GetRepository() As ResponseRepository
      Return repository
   End Function

   Public Function GetAllResponses() As IEnumerable(Of GuestResponse)
      Return responses
   End Function

   Public Sub AddResponse(response As GuestResponse)
      responses.Add(response)
   End Sub

End Class

Imports System.Web.ModelBinding

Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If IsPostBack Then
            Dim rsvp As New GuestResponse()
            If TryUpdateModel(rsvp, New FormValueProvider(ModelBindingExecutionContext)) Then
                ResponseRepository.GetRepository().AddResponse(rsvp)
                If rsvp.willAttend.HasValue And rsvp.willAttend.Value Then
                    Response.Redirect("seeyouthere.html")
                Else
                    Response.Redirect("sorryyoucantcome.html")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="PartyInvites._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="rsvpform" runat="server">
            <div>
                <h1>New Year's Eve at Jacqui's!</h1>
                <p>We're going to have an exciting party. And you're invited!</p>
            </div>
            <div><label>Your name:</label><input type="text" id="name" /></div>
            <div><label>Your email:</label><input type="text" id="email" /></div>
            <div><label>Your phone:</label><input type="text" id="phone" /></div>
            <div>
                <label>Will you attend?</label>
                <select id="willattend">
                    <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
                    <option value="true">Yes</option>
                    <option value="false">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit RSVP</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

Program runs fine till trying to get rsvp.willAttend.Value, then fails because the value is "nothing". All the values are Nothing.

I can't get out of this.
Any help? Thanks.
Edit:
The solution suggested to the referenced question (adding the tag "name" to all the variables) works.
BTW, it seems not to be the only possible solution. On the same book, few pages later, they suggest to add the tag
runat="server"
to all the variables, and even this solution works.
Can anyone explain me better the behavior with and without this tag?

Your form elements are missing the name attribute.  Without it, the browser doesn't send their values to the server.

@David This is webforms. Shouldn't the advice be to use the asp: controls rather than to include the name?

@GSerg: That's another option, sure.  The OP may be using this setup for a reason.  There's no particular inherent need to use one or the other.

Indeed, I see ZERO reason to try and use HTML input elements when a asp.net text box control is the answer here.  Regardless, if one for reasons of torture wants to use the HTML controls, they STILL require a runat="server" tag for code behind to see + use and reference such controls.

As I wrote at the beginning of my post, I'm following the track of a textbook. I can't judge the the correctness of the code the authors put inside. Probably (and hopefully) it will get better in the next chapters.

Well, as a general rule, any markup without a runat="server" means the markup element will not be processed by the asp.net engine, and thus tends to be left alone by the code behind.
And, any tag without a runat="server" also means that code behind can't see, nor touch or even know about the tag in question.
In other words, if you don't use a asp.net control, which by default (when you drag + drop say a textbox into a web form) will ALWAYS have the runat="server".
More important, is without the runat="server", then you find the designer that creates a "class" object for the page will not have any reference to standard HTML controls. So, to use code behind, and use the asp.net rendering engine (in place of simple HTML), then a runat="server" tag is required.
When you build/create a page, then a .net class in the code behind is created.
e.g. this:

So, in above, we have:
WebForm2.aspx = HTML and .net controls with runat=server
WebForm2.aspx.vb = The code behind for this page
WebForm2.aspx.designer.vb = the class object created for this page

The last "designer" page is what allows intel-sense in the code editor, and it also how asp.net engine deals with, and allows YOU the developer to reference controls directly in code behind.
So, if you are to use the asp.net development system, then if you want to use and enjoy direct referencing of controls in the markup, then such markup MUST be tagged with runat="server", else the code behind can't see nor use that markup, and standard HTML is not as a general rule accessible with code behind.
Now, you can (in most cases) use the page posted back to the server to get at some of the HTML, but when doing that, you back to an old school "post-back" model, and one that existed before .net days.
So, as per comments and suggesting here, you are to use runat="server" to force asp.net to generate code that allows code behind to reference such controls.
And in most cases, asp.net controls are much the equivalent of standard HTML controls, but you HAVE to tell asp.net to generate that code to "allow" the asp.net system to reference such controls (and it does this with the designer.vb file). If you open it up the designer file (you not to modify it directly), you will see that is it is a standard .net class object that's created for you.
It is the existence of this "page class" object that allows your code to reference and manipulate the DOM on that page. And on post back, asp.net automatic transfers the HTML markup from the DOM to the page class (it digs out all the controls with "id" tag, and runat="server" is what controls this process.
And after your code behind runs, the asp.net system transfers the values from that page class back to the DOM, and then the web page is then transmitted back to the client side. So, your code thus modifies the page class, and on the page lifecycle, the transferring of the values "to" and "from" that page class back into the markup is automatic done for you. This means you don't have to deal with messy "selectors" and other means to fetch out markup elements in your code behind.
So, for referencing of controls, then ALWAYS but ALWAYS have an "id" tag for such controls, else you have no real practical means to "identify" and enjoy use of that given control element.
And in most cases, if you add an "id" you also want to add that all important runat="server" tag. This is what "tells" the asp.net system to transfer the HTML element into the page class for you
Keep in mind, that even when using standard HTML controls, then again, adding "id" and adding runat="server means non asp.net controls will for the most part behave like a standard asp.net control.
In other words, the asp.net controls save you the developer the pain of having to add the runat="server", and saves you the pain of having to add the ID tag (it done for you, say like this).

Now, can you drag + drop a standard HTML control like above?
Sure, you can do this:

So, we now have this markup:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <input id="Text1" type="text" />

However, in code behind, since only the text box has a runat="server", then code behind can't touch, nor is any code generated that allows your code behind to modify the Text1 element.
However, as noted, by adding a runat="server", then the Text1 element will become part of the page behind class, and that is the magic part that allows code behind to touch/use/enjoy the Text1 element.
So, say we drag + drop in a button, and ALSO add a runat="server" to the non asp.net HTML input.
So, now we have this markup:
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="test button"
            OnClick="Button1_Click1"
            />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server" />

And code behind can now be this:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub


Protected Sub Button1_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    TextBox1.Text = "Server code set TextBox1"

    Text1.Value = "Server code set Text1"

End Sub

And when we run above, the result is this:

So, for the most part, you should have, and in 99% cases REQUIRE an "id" attribute for a given control. Without an "id", then how could/would you the developer reference a given control on a page? You have no real practical means, and you can often think of an "id" much like a primary key value in a database. And the rules for markup - even HTML is that you are NOT to repeat, or have one element on the page with the same ID value.
So, at the end of the day, the asp.net engine really does not have "knowledge" about markup on a given page, but the instant the given element is tagged with a runat="server", then you are now bringing into play the asp.net system, and upon having done so, then code behind (and the page class) are now able to modify the such controls and elements.
Remember, the asp.net "system" is an extension to the standard HTML post-back model that all web browsers use. However, by adopting the asp.net system, then you have a "similar" experience of that of when developing desktop software, and a bunch of HTML parsing and having to pluck values out of the markup with code is all eliminated for you. So, with a runat="server", then the asp.net engine knows to transfer values from the HTML into your page class.
So, for code behind to work, then you need both the runat="server", and you need an "id" to allow code behind to identify that element. Without both of these "tags" (more correctly called attributes), then your code behind has no means to identify and consume such controls.
Markup without a runat="server" tag, then such markup is left "as is", and is not touched nor processed by the asp.net system. Hence, such elements are just markup, and as a result such elements are not seen nor accessible by your code behind. So, runat="server" means I want the asp.net system and "engine" to deal with that markup. If you don't need code behind to change or touch that HTML markup (which is often the case for static content), then you don't need a runat="server" tag as such.
And as above shows, if you use standard HTML elements (not asp.net ones), then adding a runat="server" tends to make that HTML work like asp.net controls. That being the case, then you might as well use the asp.net controls whenever possible. And of course when you drag + drop a asp.net control from the toolbox, then a "id" is created for you, but you often (should) of course change the "id" to something more meaningful then the default control "id" generated.
